# Как в sqlite сделать подзпрос с множественным ответом (массивом)?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Пример запроса

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.row1, table1.row2 
(SELECT table2.row
FROM table2
WHERE table2.id = table1.row1) AS goods
FROM table2
```

Хочу результат вида 
1 … … {}
…

На данный момент выводит только первой значение из подзапроса, хотя записей точно больше одной.

Comment: Подробнее опишите, какие именно данные в таблицах, что запрос выводит сейчас, и что хотелось бы получить. Интуиция подсказывает, что вам нужен некий аналог ораклового [listagg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030). Для sqlite, как я понимаю, он выглядит как-то так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515267/string-aggregation-in-sqlite

Comment: А просто избавиться от подзапроса и переписать на честный LEFT JOIN с GROUP BY и GROUP_CONCAT?